# bash redirection inside file loop

Tags: bash, file, loops, redirect

I want to run a command like this:

```
while read p; grep name_ $p.config | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }' | tr p1328 p1512 > $p.1512.config ; done < allbkgds.txt
```

However, this fails with the following error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

I can't quite understand what is going wrong because the inner command works fine:

```
grep name_ $p.config | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }' | tr p1328 p1512 > $p.1512.config
```

I basically want to take some strings from the first config file and dump it into a second config file within the bash file loop.

Comment: Ah s**t, that's what's missing, I'm retarded.

Comment: @user788171, rest assured you are not :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `do` after the `while` clause